# how to show a dialog after 1 or 2 min after opning app for first time

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-dialogfragment, mobilefirst-runtime

I want to show a custom XML dialog  dialogue that will appear after a specific time in the first run, let's say after a min

how can I do it

but I'm confused about what should I do in a situation like below

- if the user open the app for the first time and just spent 30 sec and just pause the app(screen lock or in onPause) or just close the app completely

Just as a note - I have already implemented a one time show dialog(directly in main activity without any layout file ) when the app runs for the first time already

**Code**

> To view the already implemented dialog(shows up on the first run) please
> go to the  // Caution dialog (showDialog method)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer player1;
    MediaPlayer player2;
    SeekBar seekBar1;
    SeekBar seekBar2;
    TextView elapsedTimeLable1;
    TextView elapsedTimeLable2;
    TextView remainingTimeLable1;
    TextView remainingTimeLable2;
    ImageView play1;
    ImageView play2;
    int totalTime1;
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler handler1 = new Handler() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            int currentPosition1 = msg.what;
            //Update SeekBar
            seekBar1.setProgress(currentPosition1);
            // Update Timelable
            String elapsedTime1 = createTimerLable1(currentPosition1);
            elapsedTimeLable1.setText(elapsedTime1);
            String remainingTime1 = createTimerLable1(totalTime1 - currentPosition1);
            remainingTimeLable1.setText("- " + remainingTime1);

        }
    };
    int totalTime2;
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler handler2 = new Handler() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            int currentPosition2 = msg.what;
            // Update SeekBar
            seekBar2.setProgress(currentPosition2);
            // Update Timelable
            String elapsedTime2 = createTimerLable2(currentPosition2);
            elapsedTimeLable2.setText(elapsedTime2);
            String remainingTime2 = createTimerLable2(totalTime2 - currentPosition2);
            remainingTimeLable2.setText("- " + remainingTime2);

        }
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
            w.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

            // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

            // finally change the color
            w.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.Card_Elevation_Color));
        }

        // PlayButton    *  The ButtonClick is in the last if you want to jump directly there  *

        play1 = findViewById(R.id.playbtn1);
        play2 = findViewById(R.id.playbtn2);

        // TimeLables

        elapsedTimeLable1 = findViewById(R.id.cTime1);
        elapsedTimeLable2 = findViewById(R.id.cTime2);
        remainingTimeLable1 = findViewById(R.id.tTime1);
        remainingTimeLable2 = findViewById(R.id.tTime2);

        // MediaPlayer

        player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_howl);
        player1.setLooping(true);
        player1.seekTo(0);
        totalTime1 = player1.getDuration();
        player2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog_bark);
        player2.setLooping(true);
        player2.seekTo(0);
        totalTime2 = player2.getDuration();


        //SeekBar

        seekBar1 = findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
        seekBar2 = findViewById(R.id.seekbar2);
        seekBar1.setMax(totalTime1);
        seekBar2.setMax(totalTime2);

        seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress1, boolean fromUser1) {
                if (fromUser1) {
                    player1.seekTo(progress1);
                    seekBar1.setProgress(progress1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });
        seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress2, boolean fromUser2) {
                if (fromUser2) {
                    player2.seekTo(progress2);
                    seekBar2.setProgress(progress2);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        });

        // Thread (Update SeekBar & TimeLabel)
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player1 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player1.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler1.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player2 != null) {
                try {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.what = player2.getCurrentPosition();
                    handler2.sendMessage(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }).start();


        // Admob Banner Ad

        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Caution dialog

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean firstStart = preferences.getBoolean("firstStart", true);
        if (firstStart) {


            showDialog();
        }

    }

    // Caution dialog
    private void showDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Caution!")
                .setMessage("In case you're wearing any kind of headphones please remove it before playing the ' Howl ' audio")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", (dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.dismiss())
                .create().show();
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String createTimerLable1(int duration) {
        String timerLabel1 = "";
        int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;
        timerLabel1 += min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timerLabel1 += "0";
        timerLabel1 += sec;
        return timerLabel1;


    }

    public String createTimerLable2(int duration) {
        String timerLabel2 = "";
        int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
        int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;
        timerLabel2 += min + ":";
        if (sec < 10) timerLabel2 += "0";
        timerLabel2 += sec;
        return timerLabel2;


    }

    public void playBtnClick1(View view) {

        if (player2.isPlaying()) {
            player2.pause();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

        if (!player1.isPlaying()) {
            // Stoping
            player1.start();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
        } else {
            // Playing
            player1.pause();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

    }

    public void playBtnClick2(View view) {

        if (player1.isPlaying()) {
            player1.pause();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

        if (!player2.isPlaying()) {
            // Stoping
            player2.start();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24);
        } else {
            // Playing
            player2.pause();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (player1 != null) {
            player1.pause();
            play1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }
        if (player2 != null) {
            player2.pause();
            play2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm confused about what should I do in a situation like below
>
> if the user open the app for the first time and just spent 30 sec and just pause the app(screen lock or in onPause) or just close the
> app completely

This is impossible to do if your app is closed.My suggestion would be to create a service on another process that does this dialog such that even if the app process is closed,the service process will still be running unless it is stopped explicitly.
Defining a Process of a Service

> The android:process field defines the name of the process where the
> service is to run. Normally, all components of an application run in
> the default process created for the application. However, a component
> can override the default with its own process attribute, allowing you
> to spread your application across multiple processes.
>
> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), the
> service will run in its own separate process.

```
<service   android:name="com.example.appName"   android:process=":externalProcess" />
```

This is of course in the manifest file .
You might also need to show a system dialog thus you will need a system Alert Window permission i your manifest and request for the permision on runtime.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Then on runtime request like this:

```
  public static void openOverlaySettings(Activity activity) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + activity.getPackageName()));
        try {
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 6);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Drawers permission :", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

To check if granted use :

```
if(!Settings.canDrawOverlays(context)) {
            openOverlaySettings(context);
            ok=false;
        }
```

Then in your service you should create the dialog like below

```
View aldv= LayoutInflater.from(act).inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null);
        ald=new AlertDialog.Builder(act,R.style.AppTheme)
                .setView(aldv)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .create();
                ald.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

Comment: what should I add if I just want to show dialog after 1 min and that condition (i mentioned in the question) is not applied

Comment: you could just put a timer in your service or pause for a minute when the service oncreate is hit then call your dalog show after this then record somewhere the the dialog has been shown

Comment: the dialog should show regardless of if the activities all close

Comment: brother if I know this why would I ask a question on SO .the theory is ok but how do implement the time

Comment: and one more thing when i write my appName in android:name="com.example.appName" there are errors